# axis2 jar version 1.8.0 with axiom version 1.3.0 throws SOAP11HeaderImpl

Tags: soap, apache-axis, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient, axiom

We were using axis2 1.7.9 and axiom 1.2.22 in our application along with commons-httpclient 3.1. We tried removing commons-httpclient 3.1 from our application and since commons-httpclient is required by axis2 1.7.9 we had to upgrade axis2 to its latest version 1.8.0 and in process of upgrading axis2 to 1.8.0 we also upgraded axiom to 1.3.0 but when we are running our application we get below error.

```
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl is not allowed as a child of org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.soap11.SOAP11HeaderImpl
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.mixin.AxiomSOAPElementSupport.ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_soap_impl_mixin_AxiomSOAPElementSupport$org_apache_axiom_soap_impl_intf_AxiomSOAPElement$checkChild(AxiomSOAPElementSupport.aj:35)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPElement.checkChild(SOAPElement.java:1)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.mixin.AxiomContainerSupport.ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_mixin_AxiomContainerSupport$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_intf_AxiomContainer$prepareNewChild(AxiomContainerSupport.aj:160)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.prepareNewChild(OMElementImpl.java:1)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.mixin.AxiomContainerSupport.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_mixin_AxiomContainerSupport$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_intf_AxiomContainer$prepareNewChild(AxiomContainerSupport.aj)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.mixin.AxiomContainerSupport.ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_mixin_AxiomContainerSupport$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_intf_AxiomContainer$addChild(AxiomContainerSupport.aj:166)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:1)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.addHeadersToEnvelope(ServiceClient.java:673)
```

we checked and found that SOAP11HeaderImpl is child of OMElementImpl.
[image]

I am not sure why above exception is thrown.

Comment: facing same issue..

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed by https://github.com/apache/ws-axiom/commit/2d9b87f40d3851fbf0f78fe4949190f15a7977ec. There may be a simple workaround (namely to create a `SOAPHeaderBlock` instead of an `OMElement`), but unfortunately the stack trace you provided is too short to tell that.